# How do I make arrays after reading a text file

Tags: java, arrays, io

```
package telephonenumber;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class TelephoneNumber 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter name of file to read (format: fileName.txt)");
  String fileName = k.nextLine();

  Scanner ipStream = null;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
  try
  {
      ipStream = new Scanner(new File (fileName));

  }
  catch(IOException bad)
  {
              System.out.println("Error opening the file for read:" + fileName);
              System.exit(0);
  }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  while(ipStream.hasNextLine())//file is located
  {
      String dataLine = ipStream.nextLine();
      dataLine.split("  ");
      String zero = line[0];
      String one = line[1];
      String two = line[2];
      String three = line[3];
      String four = line[4];
      System.out.println(line[0]);;

  }



  System.out.println("End of file reached");
  ipStream.close();
}

}
```

My text file is a series of numbers looks like this:

- 155 156 8604
- 160 077 1405
- 774 512 5423
- 832 105 6993
- 774 563 9912

The bullets aren't in the text files. It just goes line by line.

---

How do I make each line of numbers an array?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the returned value of `split` to an array:

```
String[] line = dataLine.split("  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add each line as element you should look at `ArrayList` instead of `array` since you don't need to bother about what will be the size of your `array`. you can try as follows

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File (fileName));
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
while(sc.hashNextLine()){
  list.add(sc.nextLine());
}
```

Now your `List` contains all line. If I take an element of that `List` it will be `155 156 8604`. Now if you want to split by `" "` and get each number you can try following

```
List<String> numbers=new ArrayList<>();
for(String i:list){  
   numbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(i.split(" ")));
}
```